# When does UITableView actually display a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm aware of `-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]`, but I want to know when the `UITableViewCell` has actually been displayed.

I have a `UITextField` inside the `UITableViewCell`, and I can't call `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]` until the `UITableViewCell` (and thus the `UITextField`) are actually shown.

So far, I can do this, but it's a hack:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.textFieldIndexPath]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried overriding `-[UITableViewCell didMoveToSuperview]`, but it is only called the first time the `UITableViewCell` is added to the `UITableView`. When the `UITableViewCell` is (because the backing data changed) and then re-added (because the backing data changed again, `-[UITableViewCell didMoveToSuperview]` isn't called. I assume a `UITableView` just keeps all its `UITableViewCells` in its view hierarchy even if it isn't displaying them.

Comment: Hey, there is a delegate method didEndDisplayingCell , have you looked at that?  Not sure what you are actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to target on cell or all of them?  also, I believe that cell for row at index path is called each time a cell is displayed. typically forground type stuff goes there.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to call becomeFirstResponder directly from your UITextViewCell subclass?

Comment: @CocoaEv `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` is called for every cell, but when it is called, the cell isn't displayed. I can't call `-[UITextField becomeFirstResponder]` until the `UITextField` is an active part of the hierarchy.

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù I want to change my backing data so that my `UITextField` will be visible, and then make my `UITextField` the first responder in a clean way. The solution I have no is a hack that relies on the `UITableView` showing the `UITableViewCell` that contains the `UITextField` within the current run loop iteration.

Comment: @HeathBorders I think that what you call an hack is the right way. The UITableViewCell doesn't know if it is shown or hidden in a view hierarchy, or how it is related with the other views in the hierarchy: this is the job of the controller that manages the current shown hierarchy, in this case the UIViewController that is the delegate of the UITableView. So I think that this is the right way to go. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù The UITableViewCell doesn't know, but the UITableView does. Obviously, it _could_ tell us when individual cells are shown. I just hoped someone had a better hack than what I've proposed.

Comment: @HeathBorders are you subclassing UITableView in order to make a custom component? in that case, since UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass, you could intercept scroll events and check when the cell frame goes on screen